# How to get the city names in respond with selected country?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I need not get the city names in accordance with selected country.
I have dropdown list of countries from database.

By default users can select cities from the field i.e no restriction. But when they select country the result in cities should only get the cities of that country.

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intiGoogleLocation);
       function intiGoogleLocation() {
            var options = {
                types: ['(cities)']
            };
            if (typeof country !== 'undefined') {
                options.componentRestrictions = {country: country};
            }

            function fillInAddress() {
              //some custom logic
            }


        var input = document.getElementById('cities');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
        }
```

So question is how do i reset the option so that i can set the country to `options.componentRestrictions`

Comment: `country` must be set to the value of your select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the `change`-event of the dropdown and set the `componentRestrictions` of the autocomplete to the desired value(based on the selected dropdown-item)

```js
function intiGoogleLocation() {
  function fillInAddress() {
    //some custom logic
    console.log('place-name:'+this.getPlace().name);
  }

  var list          = document.getElementById('countries'),
      input         = document.getElementById('cities'),
      autocomplete  = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
                types: ['(cities)']
      });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed', fillInAddress);
  
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(list,'change', function(e){
    
    var componentRestrictions={};
    
    if(this.value!==''){
      componentRestrictions.country=this.value
    }
    
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(componentRestrictions);
    input.value='';
    if(e){
      autocomplete.set('place',{name:''});
    }
          
        
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(list,'change',null);
}
```

```html
<select id="countries">
  <option value="">any country</option>
  <option value="de">Germany</option>
  <option value="it">Italy</option>
  <option value="fr">France</option>
  <option value="gb">Great Britain</option>
</select>
<input id="cities"/>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=intiGoogleLocation&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```